# post file with httpcomponents. Something wrong with memory

Tags: java, http, httpclient, multipartentity

I'm trying to send file on my rest service. I'm using `apache httpcomponents 4.3.`
It works, but it use about `600 MB`. Always, if file `200 KB` or `15 GB` it use `600 MB` of Ram.

If I remove `addPart` - memory is OK.

So, why file sending get so much memory?

This is my code

```
           HttpClientBuilder clientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create();

            CloseableHttpClient client = clientBuilder.build();

            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

            MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
            builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

            builder.addTextBody("jsonData", gson.toJson(dto));
            builder.addPart("file", new FileBody(file, ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM));

            post.setEntity(builder.build());
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```

Answer (score 1):

For an older apache httpcomponents, there is a reported [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-950) of `HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE` not working. It appears it wasn't fixed.

Try changing it to:

```
MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
builder.addTextBody("jsonData", gson.toJson(dto));
builder.addPart("file", new FileBody(file));
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've tried this, but it haven't resolved the problem.